# Adding ROS to Raspberry Pi car and teleoperation

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, raspberry-pi, autonomous-car

I just completed a Raspberry Pi car setup shown in the image below.

[image: earlier image of the car build in progress]

With my car now assembled, I can run a simple Python script put the necessary GPIO pins HIGH or LOW and moves the car around successfully.

**Now, I have added ROS to the mix and I want to drive the car around using the Turtlebot teleop package.**

**Roscore** is launched and when I execute **rostopic list** I get the following:

```
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Obviously, I am missing the **/cmd_vel** topic.

**How can I make ROS aware of the robots' mobile base in order to begin driving it around, please?**

Comment: `give me direction` .... google `rpi ros`

Answer (score 1):

You first need to roslaunch the turtlebot_teleop package with

```
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

That fires up the high level teleoperation, which publishes a geometry Twist message on the cmd_vel rostopic. Looking at the launch file, it looks like it will be called `cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop`

An option for the low level code is to create your own custom ROS node that subscribes to that specific `cmd_vel` rostopic, takes the messages from the turtlebot_teleop and figures out how to properly control the motors.